# how to get the currently logged in role symfony?

Tags: symfony, role

I want to get the Role of the user currently logged. Because I want to show that in my navbar can somebody help me?

My question is about how to get the current role

Comment: what have you tried? Also is in docs ...

Comment: i tried now in my twig {{ app.user.roles }} and nothing else i use AuthorizationCheckerInterface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember well, you can get roles in twig by doing `{{ app.user && app.user.roles }}` but you will get an array of roles.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for youre response but this error has been thrown if i directly use {{app.user.roles}} in my twig this is the error: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion")

Comment: yes, because it's an array, and should be treated like that. It you want to dump all roles, you could use a custom filter like join (https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/join.html) or dump (https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html)

Comment: also don't forget to test if the user exists before acceessing `app.user.roles` to avoid unwanted errors =)

Comment: But i dont want to dump all roles. I just want to show the role that is logged in.

Comment: in Symfony, an user has an array of roles, not just one. If you are SURE that your users will allways have one and ONE ONLY role, you could do either  `{{ app.user.roles | first }}` or  `{{ app.user.roles | last }}`

Comment: Maybe this can help you understand me more: if ($authorizationChecker->isGranted(new Expression('"ROLE_INKOPER" in roles')))
        {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('homepageInkoper');
        } is there not a option to show the granted role?

Comment: It's a good example even if it's in a controller, not what he wants, but the code is still usefull to know

Comment: but can you help me maybe to get that granted role?

Comment: as I said, if your user allways have only one role and you cascaded your roles in your security.yml, you should be able to get the role of your user by just doing in your twig `{{ app.user && app.user.roles[0] }}`

Comment: Thank you very much it worked for me but is there a possibilty to change ROLE_ADMIN in the user interface for example to admin?

Comment: yep, what you should do is for example `{{ ['ROLE_ADMIN' => 'admin'][app.user.roles[0] }}`, in fact, you create an associative array and exploit it just inline =)

Comment: Better: you can define your own twig filter and do for example `{{ app.user.roles[0] | roleDisplayer }}`, check https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html for more infos =)

Comment: i got an error: Unclosed "[". i dont know how to fix it is in youre array the last one

Comment: I forgot one `]`, it's `{{ ['ROLE_ADMIN' => 'admin'][app.user.roles[0]] }}`

Answer (score 0):

you can get from current user,when we get the role,it returns array of roles

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$role = $user->getRoles();
```

in twig

```
{{app.user.roles}}
```

Comment: I just want to return the granted role in my twig.